# Using Pandas to assign specific values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        'stat': ['ordered', 'unconfirmed', 'ordered', 'unknwon', 'ordered', 'unconfirmed', 'ordered', 'back'],
        'date': ['2021', '2022', '2023', '2024', '2025','2026','2027', '1990']    
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

I am trying to get the following data frame:

[image]

Unfortunate I am not successful so far and I used the following commands (for loops) for only `stat==ordered`:

```
y0 = np.zeros((len(df), 8), dtype=int)
y1 = [1990]
if stat=='ordered':
    for i in df['id']:
        for j in y1:
            if df.loc[i].at['date'] in y1:
                  y0[i][y1.index(j)] = 1
            else:
                  y0[i][y1.index(j)] = 0
```

But unfortunately it did not returned the expected solution and beside that it takes a very long time to do the calculation. I tried to use gruopby, but it could not fgure out either how to use it perporly since it is faster than using for loops. Any idea would be very appreiciated.

Comment: I do not understand how you arrive at those numbers in those columns.  Does that not matter and you just want those values and are asking how to do it?

Comment: I did it manuely, but in case my data column is almost has 30k entries. The solution below would not be good enough to cover the issue. I tried to solve it ,but I was not able to fix it… any idea about it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df.join(
    pd.get_dummies(df.date).cumsum(axis=1).mul(
        [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0], axis=0
    ).astype(int)

)

   id         stat  date  1990  2021  2022  2023  2024  2025  2026  2027
0   1      ordered  2021     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
1   2  unconfirmed  2022     0     0     2     2     2     2     2     2
2   3      ordered  2023     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
3   4      unknwon  2024     0     0     0     0     3     3     3     3
4   5      ordered  2025     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
5   6  unconfirmed  2026     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     2
6   7      ordered  2027     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
7   8         back  1990     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```